# Devexpress pivot grid bind to vanilla SQL statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding, devexpress

I have a test DX pivot grid that I'm attempting to attach a simple SQL statement against (fairly trite example I know, but I'm just "proof of concept"ing here)

```
@Html.DevExpress().PivotGrid(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "pivotGrid";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "PivotGridPartial" };
        settings.OptionsView.ShowHorizontalScrollBar = true;
        settings.Height = new Unit(887, UnitType.Pixel);
        settings.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
        settings.OptionsCustomization.CustomizationFormStyle = CustomizationFormStyle.Excel2007;

        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\WHATEVER;Initial Catalog=WhatEver;integrated security=true;"))
        {
            con.Open();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.WhatEver", con);
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }

        settings.PreRender = (sender, e) =>
            {
                var pivot = ((MVCxPivotGrid)sender);

                pivot.DataSource = dataTable;
                pivot.RetrieveFields(PivotArea.FilterArea, false);

                pivot.BeginUpdate();
                pivot.Fields["Client"].Area = PivotArea.RowArea;
                pivot.Fields["Client"].Visible = true;
                pivot.Fields["Brand"].Area = PivotArea.RowArea;
                pivot.Fields["Brand"].Visible = true;
                pivot.Fields["Volume"].Area = PivotArea.DataArea;
                pivot.Fields["Volume"].Visible = true;
                pivot.EndUpdate();
            };

    }).GetHtml()
```

This works perfectly when it loads, but then if I try to expand one of the dimensions or change to another page the grid gets blanked out, i.e. like it has no data assigned against it.

Would anyone have an idea as to why? I can't find anything relating to pivot grids and DX that doesn't assume using an OLAP cube and the examples I have found (all around  Access) seem to be doing what I'm attempting but obviously I'm missing something!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I'm an idiot and had the datasoruce assignment in the prerender section